# Why does the distance map in scikit-skimage example not show up?

Tags: python, scikit-image, euclidean-distance, indices

I am trying to extract the diameter of a burning droplet suspended on a glass rod from highspeed camera images. Therefore I use a couple of functions from the skimage library to break down the original images to binary images with the most important data. A typical image looks like this:

**Typical reduced image**
[image: Typical reduced image]

To distinguish between the glass rod and the droplet, I want to use the watershed algorithm, which works fine. I used [this](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_segmentations.html#sphx-glr-packages-scikit-image-auto-examples-plot-segmentations-py) code to do so, but the distance map is not showing up:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import measure
from skimage.segmentation import random_walker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

# Generate an initial image with two overlapping circles
x, y = np.indices((80, 80))
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 28, 28, 44, 52
r1, r2 = 16, 20
mask_circle1 = (x - x1) ** 2 + (y - y1) ** 2 < r1 ** 2
mask_circle2 = (x - x2) ** 2 + (y - y2) ** 2 < r2 ** 2
image = np.logical_or(mask_circle1, mask_circle2)
# Now we want to separate the two objects in image
# Generate the markers as local maxima of the distance
# to the background
distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)
local_maxi = peak_local_max(
distance, indices=False, footprint=np.ones((3, 3)), labels=image)
markers = measure.label(local_maxi)
labels_ws = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=image)

markers[~image] = -1
labels_rw = random_walker(image, markers)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3.5))
plt.subplot(141)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('image')
plt.subplot(142)
plt.imshow(-distance, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('distance map')
plt.subplot(143)
plt.imshow(labels_ws, cmap='nipy_spectral', interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('watershed segmentation')
plt.subplot(144)
plt.imshow(labels_rw, cmap='nipy_spectral', interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('random walker segmentation')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The segmentation however works as intended. It produces the following output:

**Output**
[image: Output]

It also produces the following errors:

```
> <ipython-input-42-514af2735e9b>:20: FutureWarning: indices argument is
> deprecated and will be removed in version 0.20. To avoid this warning,
> please do not use the indices argument. Please see peak_local_max
> documentation for more details.   local_maxi = peak_local_max(

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\morphology\_deprecated.py:5:
> skimage_deprecation: Function ``watershed`` is deprecated and will be
> removed in version 0.19. Use ``skimage.segmentation.watershed``
> instead.   def watershed(image, markers=None, connectivity=1,
> offset=None, mask=None,

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:449:
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars   newmin = vmid
> - dv * fact

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:454:
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars   newmax = vmid
> + dv * fact

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:506:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply   A_resampled *=
> ((a_max - a_min) / frac)

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:507:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply   vrange *=
> ((a_max - a_min) / frac)
```

The second and following errors are easy to solve, the first one I found to be harder.
In an attempt to solve the first error regarding the indices argument in the peak_local_max function, I stumbled across [this](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5078) conversation on the scikit-skimage github page. They replaced two lines in the function itself, but that did not solve the issue for me. The changes are from

```py
if indices: 
     return coordinates 
else: 
     out = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.bool) 
     out[tuple(coordinates.T)] = True 
     return out
```

to

```py
if indices: 
    return coordinates 
else: 
    mask = np.zeros(im.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[tuple(indices.T)] = True
    return mask
```

I found the same two lines in another [example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html) from skimage itself, but that doesn't work for me either. I also tried converting the reduced image from binary to float, same result.

I have the feeling there is a very easy workaround, I am just too nooby to get it done myself.

I am using skimage version 0.18.2 and JupyterLab version 6.3.0.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the peak_local_max function to alter the distance array handed to it. It causes the array to include the negative of the maximum possible float value of 1.7976931348623158 E + 308. I don't know what's causing it and I won't look into it. I simply recalculate the distance array after using the peak_local_max function:

```
distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)
local_maxi = peak_local_max(
    distance, indices=False, footprint=np.ones((3, 3)), labels=image)
distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(image)
```